# "Mal disposto" é equivalente a "doente"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Posso substituir a palavra **mal disposto** por **doente**?

por exemplo:

> Comi tantos chocolates que fiquei doente.
>
> Comi tantos chocolates que fiquei mal disposto.

Comment: Olá Majid. Fiz algumas edições na tua pergunta. Como sempre: se não concordares com as edições, edita a pergunta para ela ficar como tu queres! :)

Comment: @ANeves Valeu para edição!

Comment: Majid, você não dispõe de un dicionário árabe<>português? https://clunl.fcsh.unl.pt/investigacao/projetos-curso/dicionario-de-portugues-europeu-arabe-padrao/ Por exemplo. Eu sei, não é português brasileiro mas vale a pena.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em princípio não: não podes usar "estar mal-disposto" onde usas "doente", ou vice-versa.
Mas quem está doente normalmente também está mal-disposto.

Estar doente é "to be sick: to have a disease".
Estar mal-disposto é "to feel sick: to feel bad, unwell, indisposed".

- Se estiveres enjoado por andar de carro, estás ✅ mal-disposto mas ❌ não estás doente;
- Se tiveres manchas na pele por causa de [dermatite](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatite) (mas não tiveres comichão), ❌ não estás mal disposto mas ✅ estás doente;
- E se tiveres comichão na pele por causa de [dermatite](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatite), ✅ estás mal disposto e ✅ estás doente.

"Estar mal disposto" é uma sensação. Uma pessoa que está mal-disposta (de [disposição](https://dicionario.priberam.org/disposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) sente-se desconfortável, sente-se mal: **sentir**.
Esta sensação pode ser física (enjoado por andar de carro) mas também emocional (muito irritado e preocupado porque o cão está perdido na floresta).

"Estar doente" é uma condição médica física (ou psiquiátrica, ou...). Uma pessoa que está doente tem uma doença: **illness**.